# Isn't Angular Universal just the same old JSP/ASP pages, only less coherent and more compicated to set up?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Sorry about the provocative question title, but really, where are the differences?

As far as I get it, the message is something like: "with SPA there might be some performance problems owed to the fact that the DOM is being processed by the javascript running in the browser; so let us render the pages on the server to eliminate this overhead to make things faster!"

Of course it then might introduce issues due to the fact that Angular was meant to work in the browser, not on Node.js server.

So again my question is are there any differences between Angular Universal and the "good old" server side pages, and what value if any Angular Universal adds in comparison?

Comment: With server side rendering you are pre-rendering a SPA, you're just delegating all the job of the browser to a server. There's no connection with JSP/AP

Comment: Then, Angular works mainly in a browser but it wasn't designed to run **only** in a browser. You can use Angular also to create a desktop application or a smartphone application. If it doesn't work so fine in a server is just because it's not mature enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that angular universal just renders the first page. It then transfers the state to the browser and will not do another server roundtrip. In JSP this is different. The State will only be kept on the server and you have to do another server roundtrip if you want to display a new page for example.